# Drupal empty view still renders

Tags: drupal, view, is-empty

well yeah, I have a weird issue, There is a view that return empty fields (no records), the thing is that this view even returning no records prints an empty div.., so I have tried putting filter criterias for all my fields (Not Null and all that), I have tried CONTEXTUAL FILTERS with global: null (Hide view), the format settings "Hide empty fields", well I do not want to end writing a script to do it for me :(.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try changing the base entity of the view.  In my experience, this happens when the data returned is all related to fields joined to a base entity.  The base entity exists, but values for the joined fields do not, so the view still returns a result, but all the selected fields are empty.